# Exercise 3.1.4 in Grimmett & Stirzaker's 'Probability and Random Processes'

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $S_k$ be the set of positive integers whose base-10 expansion contains exactly k elements (so that for example, $1024 \in S_4$). A fair coin is tossed until the first head appears, and we write T for the number of tosses required. We pick a random element, N say, from $S_T$, each such element having equal probability. What is the mass function of N?

The solution

Let $D_k$ be the number of digits (to base 10) in the integer k. Then

$$P(N=k) = P(N=k|T = D_k)P(T=D_k)=\frac{1}{|S_{D_k}|}2^{-D_k}$$

I believe that the as all elements are equally likely part is:

$$P(N=k|T = D_k)=2^{-D_k}$$

Can someone explain how

$$P(T=D_k)=\frac{1}{|S_{D_k}|}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your expressions may have errors.  If, for example,  you consider $k=246$ then

- $D_k= \lceil\log_{10}(k+1)\rceil=3$ since $246$ has three digits
- $P(T=D_k)={2^{-D_k}}=\frac18$ as the probability of two tails followed by a heads
- $|S_{D_k}|=\frac{9}{10} \times 10^{D_k}=900$ since $S_{D_k}=\{100,101,\ldots,999\}$ the three digit integers
- $P(N=k\mid T=D_k) =\dfrac{1}{|S_{D_k}|}= \dfrac1{900}$ since all the three digit integers are equally likely
- $P(N=k) =\dfrac{2^{-D_k}}{|S_{D_k}|}=\dfrac{10}{9\times 20^{D_k}}= \dfrac1{7200}$ as you need two tails followed by a heads and then to chose a specific three digit integer. You could write this last expression as $P(N=k) =\dfrac{10}{9 \times 20^{\lceil\log_{10}(k+1)\rceil}}.$

Answer (score 1):

No. The "equally likely" part gives you an uniformly and randomly chosen element from $S_{D_{k}}$ and hence the $\dfrac{1}{|S_{D_{k}}|}$ part. i.e. the probability of picking one particular integer from the set of integers with $D_{k}$ many digits is just $\dfrac{1}{|\text{integers with }D_{k}\,\text{many digits}|}=\dfrac{1}{|S_{D_{k}}|}$

The $\dfrac{1}{2^{D_{k}}}$ is for $P(T=D_{k})$, i.e. the probability that it takes $D_{k}$ many tosses to get the first head. The probabiliy of that is the product of the first $D_{k}-1$ tosses being tails and the last one being heads. As each toss is head or tail with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and the tosses are independent, you get $\dfrac{1}{2^{D_{k}}}$ as the probability.